# Samsung android sdk source/binary mismatch

Tags: android

I have a samsung grand duos device, not rooted, uses android 4.2.2 (sdk v.17). The problem is that the line info for phone android sdk binaries don't correspond to the public android sdk sources.

Example:

[image]

Couple of things interest us here:

1. The device reports that it uses sdk v.17 (that's the value of android.od.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT obtained via debugger connected to the device);
2. The stacktrace shows that android.widget.ListView.setupChild() calls android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInLayout() at line 1886. The problem is that source code doesn't have a call to addViewInLayout() instruction at the line 1886;

I also checked android sources for the sdk v.17 in order to exclude IDE interference -

[image]

It shows the same information though (no call to addViewInLayout() at ListView:1886)

The only explanation I see is that samsung guys assemble their own slightly modified android sdk and use it at their phones (at least for my device). However, googling didn't confirm that.

Questions:

1. Has anybody encountered that problem?
2. Any idea on what else might cause such a behavior?

Comment: "The only explanation I see is that samsung guys assemble their own slightly modified android sdk and use it at their phones (at least for my device)" -- device manufacturers modify the framework all the time. So long as they do not break the public APIs, this usually causes only limited problems (e.g., trying to extend context menus of an `EditText`).

Comment: Pretty much the only devices were the source code lines match perfectly are Nexuses. Probably Google Editions of other devices too, but haven't tested it.

Comment: That's too bad that there is no source code correspondence because there is a problem at ListView processing at the device (related to my custom logic of transient state manipulation for list items) and I'm unable to debug the exact processing details :(

Comment: Can you replicate the problem on an emulator?